# How to keep personalized string after content deletion

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, dataextensions

Exacttarget HTML AMPSCRIPT question

Hi I am inserting a few personalized strings from a data extension in an email.

For example: "Dear %%NAME%% your order number %%order%%"

The thing is it works fine until the data remains in the data extension, but as it is this data extensions is overwritten daily with new info sent in new emails.
Does anyone know a workaround to this?

Obs: Things like %%emailaddr%% remain since they are contact related and not data extension related. I was wondering if there is some function **similar** to putting the "1" inside the "now()" function, which keeps the send date instead of the now date.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use-case for Send Logging - I would contact support to get this enabled.  Send Logs allow you to capture custom send-time attributes stored in a data extension.  However, you'd need to do a lookup on this to determine those values within the content itself.

A more robust, data-focused approach (that doesn't require support intervention) is to make a copy of this data extension, and APPEND the same data that overwrites your sendable DE to this new copy.  Essentially, you are importing the data in two identical DEs, but one will not be overwritten and one will.

Comment: for the second option should I use the lookup to find the data on this second data extension?

Comment: In this case, I don't think it would matter - however, if you use something like a "View In A Browser" link, this does require the data to be persistent.  This means you'd need to do the lookup on the second data extension as you suggested, the one with the persistent data.